# How can i build apache httpd statically?

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to build an apache httpd server that will be able to run under multiple linux os (RH, SUSE, e.t.c.)

The main problem is that httpd is using shared libraries:

```
ldd httpd/bin/httpd
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff955fe000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fec3df54000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fec3dd4c000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fec3db14000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fec3d8f7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fec3d564000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fec3e183000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fec3d301000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fec3d0fd000)
```

On 1 of the servers this is causing httpd to fail because of old glibc package:

```
ldd httpd 
./httpd: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by ./httpd)
./httpd: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by ./httpd)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00002b1e6b55d000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00002b1e6b680000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00002b1e6b789000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b1e6b8c3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b1e6b9dc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b1e6b441000)
```

Updating glibc on the system is not an option unfortunately.

Is there a correct way of compiling apache httpd with static libraries?

Comment: It's not very likely that you need to do this. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to create a package that will be persistent across multiple servers with different OS.

Comment: That's clear enough. What's not clear is _why_. On its face, this is "doing it wrong".

Comment: I needed to do this, in order to obtain a standalone copy of the 'ab' test utility.

Answer (score 4):

Building a static version of httpd requires usage of a legacy configure flag "--disable-shared" with "./configure".
http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/360330

Answer (score 3):

> I need to build an apache httpd server that will be able to run under multiple linux os (RH, SUSE, e.t.c.)

No you don't. You have a problem that you're trying to solve by static linking. Static linking is a horrible solution from the previous century and should not be done anymore. Please try to find a different way of solving your actual problem.

Comment: So basically you are saying that I don't have another option, but to update every OS on every server?
And if I don't have the possibility to do that?

Comment: @user166655, keeping _servers_ (Internet-facing ones at that) without careful management (which, inter alia, includes rigurous updating) is just irresponsible. And if there are several, it isn't that you can't install e.g. [CentOS](http://centos.org) for free. Uniform operating system across the board means less headaches (including what you are trying to do).

Comment: If you don't have the possibility to do that, you'll need to explain why, as that's highly suspicious. But yes, stick to distro-provided packages as much as possible and always update for security patches.

Comment: This package I'm creating will be used only locally on servers that are not open to internet. Package installation and os upgrade is highly complicated and will take quite a long time, that is why I was looking for a quick and better solution.

Comment: What's highly complicated about 'yum update'? Or even just 'yum update httpd'? It's *far* more complicated to keep your server secure with a statically compiled apache. Security doesn't end at the internet facing part of your network. Somebody could penetrate that and proceed from there, or an internal person could decide to do something malicious.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple. There are a lot of policies and procedures we need to go through to install some simple package. No root access, just a simple 1 user environment.

Comment: And how is installing and updating your custom apache going to be any simpler? You'll still need to go through the policies and need root access to do it.

Comment: I'm starting to understand that I had to write another question. The thing is that this apache will be installed under non-root user. Again these are servers with limited or even no root access at all. That is why I need to compile this and use in a non-root environment. So I could build it and update myself.

Comment: Your idea keeps getting worse. Are you sure you're allowed to do this and not subverting your company's it/security policies?